# How to drop feature with the smallest value of coefficient?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
while True and nFeatures >=3 :
    #Print co-efficients of features
    for i in range(0, nFeatures):
        print (samples.columns[i],":", coef[0][i])
    
    #Find the minimum weight among features and eliminate the feature with the smallest weight
    min = coef[0][0]
    index = 0
    for i in range(0, rfeIndex):
        if min > coef[0][i]:
            index = index + 1
            min = coef[0][i]
    if len(samples.columns) == 1:
        print ("After recursive elimination we have the", samples.columns[index], "feature with a score of:", min)
        accuracy(model, x_test, y_test)
        break
    else:
        print ("Lowest feature weight is for", samples.columns[index], "with a value of:", min)
        print ("Dropping feature", samples.columns[index])

        #Drop the feature in the 'samples' dataframe based on the lowest feature index
        samples.drop(samples.columns[index], axis = 1, inplace = True)
        y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
        accuracy(model, x_test, y_test)
        print ("\n")
        rfeIndex = rfeIndex - 1
        nFeatures = nFeatures - 1
```

and the result is :
[image]
I dont know why it calls wrong index but the value is right.
The result must be PAY_AMT5 because the value of it is -1.593807954123289.
but in my program it called Age
Someone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is the error in this line:

```
index = index + 1
```

because the "index" variable is incremented by one only when a new minimum is found. Instead of adding one to the "index", it is worth equating the "indexn" variable to the variable "i". Just change the line with increasing "index" variable to the next one:

```
index = i
```

And one more thing: in python, it is not welcome to create variables with a name that matches some functions, for example, "min", as it leads to an error in calling this function. Therefore, it is worth changing the name of the variable "min" to, for example, "min_coeff".